# d3js path generator in collapsible tree layout

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

I have been learning the d3js and had this question that I barely can find a good reference on the web:

In this demo code:

Collapsible Tree http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I found below snip is critical to the collapse/expand behaivor of a node:

```
  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
```

Could anyone explain more that why the data has to be set with d.target.id here? or if someone can redirect me to the reference that explains, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `.data()` is a function that tells D3 how to match data elements to DOM elements. By default, it does this by the index, i.e. the first data item matches the first DOM element, the second the second and so on. In this case, this doesn't work as the data needs to be matched on the ID of the target (or something similar that uniquely identifies a link).

For more information, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data).